# Radare2 forwarding input to scanf from a file

Tags: radare2

I'm debugging a file with radare2 and when I come to `scanf` function I want to forward input from a .txt file. In gdb I would do this by typing `r < text.txt`.

Is something like that possible in radare2? I've tried `dc < text.txt` but it seems that it's not working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Always ensure you use radare2 git version.**

For that purpose you can use `rarun2`:

For stdio check what is the tty using `tty` for stdin just add what file you want to add, then in your rarun2 config file:

```
#!/usr/bin/rarun2
stdio=/dev/pts/1
stdin=./pattern.txt
```

Then just `r2 -d /bin/ls -e dbg.profile=bla.rr2`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment [maijin](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/users/3721/maijin) answer, but due to [that answer](https://github.com/radareorg/radare2/issues/9788#issuecomment-412233079)(*r2 issue #9788*) passing params after **-d** flag can get side effects.

> ... don't pass flags after -d or may be taken as args of the program
>   in some systems.